# Render a translation with variable for a Bootstrap checkbox in Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig, bootstrap-4, symfony4

In a Symfony 4 project, I use Bootstrap theme for rendering my HTML stuff.

I have a form which contains a checkbox for accepting terms like:

> ☑ I accept [terms](http://google.com)

I want to get the link as a variable (will change depending of language)

So I have a translation yaml like this :

```
form:
  register:
    title: Registration
    username: Username
    email: Email
    password: Password
    repeat_password: Repeat your password
    accept_terms: Accept %terms%
```

In my `formType` file, I can't inject the translation because I found nothing to feed the `%terms%` parameter.

```
->add(
    'termsAccepted',
    CheckboxType::class,
    [
        'mapped' => false,
        'constraints' => new IsTrue(),
        'label' => 'form.register.accept_terms',
    ]
)
```

In twig file I can't change the form_label because... in Symfony [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/bootstrap4.html#labels-and-errors), it says that `form_label` doesn't work for checkbox (and radio button)

```
{{ form_label(form.termsAccepted, 'that custom label is ignored...') }}
```

Any idea on how to send a translation (with parameter) on a checkbox element (Bootstrap 4)?

## SOLUTION

In my form twig :

```
{% form_theme form.termsAccepted _self %}

{% block checkbox_label -%}
    ... here is a copy/paste of the orignial code from https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig ...

        {{ widget|raw }}
        <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>
        {% set terms_link = '<a href="http://url.com">'~'form.register.terms_link'|trans()~'</a>' %}
        {{- label is not same as(false) ? (translation_domain is same as(false) ? label|raw : label|trans({'%terms%': terms_link}, translation_domain)|raw) -}}
        {{- form_errors(form) -}}
        </label>
    {%- endif -%} {%- endblock checkbox_label %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view you could insert, at the top, this

```
{% form_theme form.termsAccepted _self %}
```

as written here in the docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#child-forms

And then you could overwrite the checkbox_label shipped in bootstrap 4 form theme with the one you need. Just write

```
{% block checkbox_label %}
    Copy and paste here the same block from bootstrap 4 form them and edit as your needs. See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig
{% endblock %}
```

This custom block will be used only for form.termsAccepted.

If you want a more generic solution you can create your own type (e.g. `CheckboxlinkType` that extends `CheckboxType`, add the needed options (linkUri and linkText) in `configureOptions` and pass their value to the view in `buildView`. Then you can write the specific block you need to render your type, called `checkboxlink_label` using the one in bootstrap 4 form theme as base and using your variables. Let me know if you need help with this.

Comment: Thank you, I'll go with that solution. For your information, in my case of bootstrap templating, I do need `{% block checkbox_label -%}` (not checkbox_widget).
I will edit my post to add the solution for everyone interrested.
Still a weird behavior I can't explain : for properly print my link I need to add filter `|raw` on both statements : `label|raw` **AND** `label|trans({'%terms%': terms_link}, translation_domain)|raw)` (see it in my original post)

Comment: Other problem I encounter, I can't pass variable from controller to the {% block checkbox_label -%} in my form twig. Do you know how to do it ?
That's exactly (but not solved) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757770/inject-variable-into-extended-twig-form-theme . So I guess the best choice for me is to create a custom form field type.

Comment: @shabang as I said, if you want a more generic solution you have to create your own Type, eg `CheckboxlinkType`.  See https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html, setting the `Parent` as `CheckboxType`, adding `linkUri` and `linkLabel` in `configureOptions` (with `setDefined`) and sending them to the view in `buildView`. Then you make your own block `{% block mycheckbox_label %} in the general template (https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#twig).

Comment: When you'll instanciate (with `add`) your brand-new type you will pass the actual values for `linkUri` and `linkLabel` in the third parameter (with `label`, `constraints`, etc.)

Comment: Take a look at this `Type` as example https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/MoneyType.php

Comment: Yeah, creating my own type is definitly the best solution. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to customising the template through the form theme is to translate the label in your form type and disable the translation performed in the template:

```
->add('termsAccepted', CheckboxType::class, [
    'mapped' => false,
    'constraints' => new IsTrue(),
    'label' => $this->translator->trans('form.register.accept_terms', [
        '%terms%' => 'foo',
    ],
    'translation_domain' => false,
])
```

You will have to add a `TranslatorInterface` argument to your form type's constructor, register it as a service and inject the `translator` service here.

Comment: I think that with this solution you can't output an html tag for the link  to the terms because of output escaping.

Comment: Thx, I tried your solution and it works fine but as mentioned by @ste, HTML is escaped. Other 'cons' is that it force me to add a service with a dependency. As far as I want to make a shared bundle for my user bundle, I won't prefer that solution.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that you need to output HTML here. For that, you will indeed have to customise the form theme.